# Cake or PHP feature or bug?

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm a PHP greenhorn, so please be patient with me, but I've just bumped into something I don't understand. I have PHP 5.3 and CakePHP 1.3.10.

I have a Helper called Phone with method formPhoneNum(). When I call, in my view, this:

```
echo $this->Phone->formPhoneNum('+420111222333');
```

everything works all right. When I call this:

```
$Phone = '+420111222333';
echo $this->Phone->formPhoneNum($Phone);
```

everything works all right as well. But, when I call this:

```
$phone = '+420111222333';
echo $this->Phone->formPhoneNum($phone);
```

I get this:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function formPhoneNum() on a non-object in .../view.ctp on line 3
```

Isn't that cool? :-D

Comment: ... and why Stackoverflow always strips my "Hello," greeting on the first line? Isn't that cool too? :-D

Comment: Seems that $this->Phone is not an object in the last example... Did you test the three examples within the same context?. Check what $this->Phone is using:   var_dump ($this->Phone).

Comment: @Cezar I always wrote "Hello" and "thank you" but this was removed several times by other members of SO because it is "useless" text ;-) So I think it strips it because it is useless :D

Comment: @strauberry Oh, I see. It's sad a bit, isn't it. But my Hello disappears directly after submit. Mabye SO has some sophisticated filters for it :-)

Comment: @jjmontes Yes, I have tested this within the same context, I mean, I haven't changed anything else. I just played with these two lines.

Comment: @Petr: Yes, there is something more sophisticated, based on this: http://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/77656671614275584

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any helper you create is available from both `$this->helperName` and `$helperName`, when you assign `$phone = ''`, you are overwriting the PhoneHelper. This is behaviour won't exist in 2.0 and you will only be able to use `$this->helperName`.

Comment: That's it! You are right, thank you. Cool feature, isn't it... I just wonder about turning it off. :-)